# Bytebuffer in Java

Tags: java, udp, bytebuffer

I send long number via UDP.

```
    LinkedQueue Q = new LinkedQueue<ByteBuffer>();
    while (this._run) {
    udp_socket.receive(packet);
      if (packet.getLength() > 0) {
       ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buf, 0, packet.getLength());     
               Q.add(bb);
          }
    }
```

//udp close. I remove data from Queue, but all ByteBuffers have same value.

```
    while(!Q.isEmpty){
      ByteBuffer b = Q.remove();
      b.getLong();//same value
    }
```

Why i receive same value? Any Suggest?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And how big is the bytebuffer?

Comment: Question is :I remove data from Queue, but all ByteBuffers have same value.

Comment: Are you reusing the same `buf` object? And you don't seem to take any data from the `packet` either?

Comment: I debugged: all b that removed from Q has same backingarray id

Comment: They probably refer to `buf`.

Answer (score 1):

Does your byte buffer consists of just one `long`?

Probably not, my guess is that you put a bit too much for just one `long` in there. 
And that's why it gives you same values on first `sizeof(long)` bytes.

What you need to do is to keep calling .getLong() until you hit the end of the buffer.

[See the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getLong%28%29)